# How to create sub-collections?

Tags: collections

How can I create sub-collections? Like a collection inside another collection. I only found how to do it using python, is there any easier way that doesn't envolve coding? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you select a collection in the outliner, right mouse click -> new.

Then you create a new collection in your selected collection.

Comment: Thank you so much! :)

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: You can also click drag an release an existing collection over another collection to make it a sub collection